# Batch Script Doesnt Delete Folders in a Folder .txt File :(

Tags: batch-file, cmd, command

My batch file's code is:

```
for /f "delims=" %%f in (7profiledeletelist.txt) do rd /s /q "%%f"
PAUSE
exit
```

In "7profiledeletelist.txt", there are: (will be deleted)

```
C:\Users\1* (I tried *.* it didnt work)
C:\Users\2* (I tried *.* it didnt work)
C:\Users\3* (I tried *.* it didnt work)
C:\Users\4* (I tried *.* it didnt work)
C:\Users\5* (I tried *.* it didnt work)
C:\Users\6* (I tried *.* it didnt work)
C:\Users\7* (I tried *.* it didnt work)
C:\Users\8* (I tried *.* it didnt work)
C:\Users\9* (I tried *.* it didnt work)
C:\Users\M* (I tried *.* it didnt work)
C:\Users\T* (I tried *.* it didnt work)
```

But via this **7profiledeletelist.txt**, bat file can not delete anything. If I remove * and If I write exact name it's working well. I want to delete all folders starting with M-T and 1 to 9 in Users. How can I change "7profiledeletelist.txt" or batch script. Is there a mistaken code in batch script? Thank you in advance :(

And can we add exclusion folders (for ex: folder 325 and folder 265) to this batch, not to be deleted?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`rd` will not accept a wildcard, so, the wildcard needs to be converted in a complete reference to a folder. Use an additional `for`

```
for /f "delims=" %%f in (7profiledeletelist.txt) do (
    for /d %%a in ("%%f") do rd /s /q "%%~fa"
)
```

**edited** to adapt to comments. How to exclude folders in the process

```
(
    cmd /q /c "(for /f "delims=" %%f in (7profiledeletelist.txt) do for /d %%a in ("%%f") do echo(%%~fa)" 
) | ( 
    for /f "delims=" %%a in ('findstr /l /v /g:exclude.txt') do @rd /s /q "%%a"
)
```

The first command will generate the list of all the folders and the second will filter this list, filtering out the folders indicated in the `exclude.txt` file. This file needs to contain a line for each excluded file. The real requirements will determine the format of the line or the parameters of the `findstr` command.

Comment: How can we add exception folders (not to be deleted) to this code? For ex: Folder Name: is 235812 and 35284?

Comment: First, it didnt work after I removed second "echo" in code it worked :) Thank you again

Comment: @serdar, yes, my fault. I forget to remove the `echo` used in tests.